# Call a child class method when setting the base class property

Tags: delphi

I'm creating custom components. This custom component is inherited from TControl which have a TAlign property. I want to execute a method from my descending classes whenever TAlign is set a value

This is the draft of the descending class:

```
  TWidget = class(TControl)
  public
    procedure Resize;
  end;
```

When I write a value to TAlign (From TControl class), another method, from TWidget is called. Like so:

```
var
   t: TWidget;
begin
   t := TWidget.Create(Self);
   t.Align := alRight; // When this is executed, "Resize" from TWidget should be called
```

Comment: Why is Align special. There are countless ways to change the position and size of a control. I suspect you've asked the wrong question.

Comment: It's not special, its just an example. I don't want to create all the variables like Left, Top, Height again, that's why I inherited it from TControl.I need my class to be aware of the changes happening in its upper class so I can reposition my control. Let's suppose that I create a control aligned left, then for some reason, I need to change it to the right, and by doing so I need to align another set of components.

Comment: You can override TControl.Resize and call your Resize procedure from there. Not sure though if I understand the question - not being asked one doesn't help.

Comment: The `Align` property in `TControl` calls `SetAlign`, which is private to the base class and is not abstract or virtual, so you can neither access it from a descendent, nor can you override its behaviour.  You could maybe do this with a helper, interposer, or possibly RTTI, though that is probably a poor option for a number of reasons.

Comment: Hi Sertac. Let's stick to the first example. Let's suppose that I change the Align property at run time by doing "t.Align := alRight;". I can't override the SetAlign method, since it's private to TControl class. How can I keep track of property changes in the descending class?

Comment: I think J's comment addresses that. What's the problem with overriding Resize, your control will be resized after its alignment changes after all?

Comment: Keep previous alignment somewhere and override DoCanResize, it's called with the new alignment and before the control is resized.

Comment: It's a good approach @SertacAkyuz, would work too. In the special case of TAlign, i'll reintroduce the variable in my class and create my own SetAlign method, since after TAlign is set, the Resize method is not called. Thank you and J... for for time. I will post a answer soon

Comment: Well, there's TControl.RequestAlign and TControl.WMWindowPosChanged that would be worth investigating too, depending on needs.

Comment: That's not a real solution to your problem. But it's not clear that you want one. You've decided what the solution is and you aren't ready to reconsider.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan. The problem: Track property value across descending classes. What was discussed: It depends on how the methods and properties were implemented on the base class.
Possible solutions for the specific problem (TAlign property in TControl class): Call RequestAlign, DoCanResize, use the PosChanged message, reintroduce the variable and else (as discussed with Ken, J... and Sertac). I'll post all these as possible answers in a moment. I think it is a real solution

Comment: I'll. And i'll post it as possible solution to the question. Thanks @KenBourassa

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a control's `Align` property is changed, it calls the control's `SetBounds()` and `RequestAlign()` methods.

`SetBounds()` is `virtual`, so a descendant can `override` it directly.  This is also the same method that is called by the control's `Left`, `Top`, `Width`, and `Height` property setters.  After applying the new bounds, `SetBounds()` issues a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message to the control (which can be caught by `override`'ing the control's virtual `WndProc()` method, or by subclassing its `WindowProc` property, or by declaring a `message` handler), as well as calls the `RequestAlign()` and `Resize()` methods.

`RequestAlign()` calls `Parent.AlignControl()`, which does a lot of work, but it basically boils down to simply repositioning each of the `Parent`'s visible child controls relative to each other based on their respective `Align` and `Anchors` values.  Those repositions are done by calling `SetBounds()` on each child control.

`Resize()` just fires the control's `OnResize` event handler, if assigned.

So, the best way to have your custom control react to changes in its size or position is to simply `override` its `SetBounds()` method, or handle the `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message, eg:

```pascal
type
  TWidget = class(TControl)
  public
    procedure SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer); override;
  end;

procedure TWidget.SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight: Integer);
begin
  inherited SetBounds(ALeft, ATop, AWidth, AHeight);
  // use Left/Top/Width/Height properties as needed...
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
type
  TWidget = class(TControl)
  protected
    procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;
  end;

procedure TWidget.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited WndProc(Message);
  if Message.Msg = WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED then
  begin 
    // use Left/Top/Width/Height properties as needed...
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```pascal
type
  TWidget = class(TControl)
  private
    procedure WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged); message WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED;
  end;

procedure TWidget.WMWindowPosChanged(var Message: TWMWindowPosChanged);
begin
  inherited;
  // use Left/Top/Width/Height properties as needed...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, helpful as always!